# Unexpected Error when attempting to save a site as a template in SharePoint 2010

Tags: site-template

I'm a site owner for my company and am new to SharePoint in general.  I'm trying to save a site as a template to be used for future sites.  When I "Save site as template" from the Site Settings options, I get the following:

> Error
>   An unexpected error has occured.
>   Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation
>   Correlation ID: *Lists a long alpha-numeric code here*
>   Date and Time:

We have done and checked everything I know to do.  Our site is SharePoint Designer enabled, I have full access (That I know of).  This just isn't working.  Are there any known issues?  Something I might try?

Comment: what is you site template, publishing or team? also check the ULS logs for the correlation ID to get the idea why it is failing

Comment: if you have access to server run the below powershell to get the detail about the error: merge-splogfile -correaltion -path c:\loh.log

Answer (score 1):

If this is a publishing site, it is not fully supported to save it as a template. Check if the publishing feature is enabled on Site collection or Site level:

```
Site settings --> Manage Site collection features
```

and

```
Site settings --> Manage Site features
```